# Screen garbled only in certain windows

Tags: windows-8.1, display, lenovo-laptop

My screen starts getting corrupted/garbled once in a while(mostly when I'm playing DOTA). This does not happen in the game though, only when I ALT+TAB to the desktop. The screen goes back to normal when I switch to chrome or any other window. It goes back to being garbled when i switch back to the desktop. My system does run a bit hot when i play games, but i have seen this problem even when it's pretty cool.

I have a Lenovo y500 with a Nvdia gt650M GPU and I am running Windows 8.1 . I started facing this problem a few days ago(I am not sure if the problem is because of a windows update, but I had updated it a couple of weeks ago.)

I took a small video of the screen  - [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox0lbjc25n1temk/20150624_154056.mp4?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Updating your graphics driver to the latest version will fix this issue.

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Use the search feature to find the latest version for your specified GPU and OS version.

If you are given the option to do a clean install, choose this option. It will remove the current driver and install the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my drivers, will monitor the situation for a while and let you know.